# Include dropdown in search with possible search names

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have the following code, but this code only works for EXACT matches in db, what I would like is for example you want to search "John Jones", If you type just joh his name along with other users of the same name will appear in dropdown, as well as jone for last name.
I have tried a couple with the 'LIKE' functions but I cant seem to figure it out.
Thank you!

```
<?php
    include ('core/init.php');

    logged_in_redirect();

    if(empty($_POST['friend_search'])) {
        header('Location: friends.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

        <title> My Friends</title>
        <link href='css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    </head>
    <body class='home-body'>
        <?php include_once("core/analyticstrackingcode.php") ?>
        <div class='whitebg'>
            <?php include('core/navbar.php'); ?>
            <?php
                $friend = $_POST['friend_search'];
                $found=0;
                $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
                    $possible_match_name = $row['first_name'];
                    $possible_match_id = $row['id'];
                    $possible_match_email = $row['email'];
                    $possible_match_profilepic = $row['profilepic'];
                    $this_users_email = $_SESSION['email'];
                    if($possible_match_email!=$this_users_email) {
                        if($friend==$possible_match_email) {
                            echo "
                                <html>
                                    <div class='friendsearchentries'>
                                        <img src='$possible_match_profilepic' class='friend-match-prof-pic' />
                                        <a href='confirm_send.php?id=$possible_match_id' class='friend-match-link' ><center>".$possible_match_name."</center></a>
                                    </div>
                                </html>";
                                $found=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($found==0) {
                    echo "Sorry, we found no matches.";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LIKE in your SQL query instead:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx

Comment: I have tried that, but I cant seem to get it working on my script!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MyISAM or InnoDB engines with MySQL, you can use some of the built in full-text search functions.

You'll be able to do stuff like:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (first_name, email) AGAINST ('john jones' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

This is really useful for building search-as-you-type functionality using a PHP API and Ajax, for example.

Definitely have a read about these, and you'll probably need to do a little work with your DB to find out if it's running MyISAM or InnoDB, and possibly a little bit of configuration.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html